# Pros and cons of using only express+react instead of express+react+jade/ejs

Tags: node.js, express, reactjs, pug, ejs

- using react as engine https://github.com/reactjs/express-react-views vs
- calling react renderToString and then reander with other engine https://strongloop.com/strongblog/node-js-react-isomorphic-javascript-why-it-matters/
- may be others like res.send  + renderToString

Comment: https://github.com/jadejs/react-jade